# IE not applying styles from stylesheet

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser, zurb-foundation

Good day everyone. I am having a weird issue with IE. IE is loading my stylesheets correctly, but it is not applying styles to a specific group of pseudo selectors.

I am using Foundation and an icon font (icomoon) which loads from one stylesheet and has styles applied to them from another. Chrome/Safari/Firefox all correctly apply the styles to the 'class':before elements. IE however does not. Using F12 tools I can see the stylesheet loads properly and have verified this using Fiddler.

The CSS which is not being applied is:

```
.icon-bookmarks:before, .icon-blog:before, .icon-bullhorn:before, .icon-info2:before, .icon-lab:before, .icon-bookmarks2:before, .icon-bullhorn2:before, .icon-mail:before, .icon-blog2:before, .icon-graduation:before, .icon-user:before, .icon-users2:before {
color: #fff;
font-size: 6rem;
position: absolute;
top: 2.5rem;
left: 38%;
left: calc(50% - 5.5rem);
border: 5px solid white;
padding: 2.5rem;
margin-top: 2.5rem;
border-radius: 50%; }

.icon-bullhorn:before, .icon-info2:before, .icon-lab:before, .icon-bookmarks2:before, .icon-mail:before, .icon-blog2:before, .icon-facebook:before, .icon-twitter:before, .icon-linkedin:before, .icon-graduation:before, .icon-user:before, .icon-users2:before {
color: #3e729a;
border-color: #3e729a;
margin-top: 0; }
```

The HTML is:

```
<div id="featured" class="ss-style-triangles">
    <div class="icon-bookmarks row">
       <h1 class="white">Featured Event</h1>
        <!--Content Stripped-->
    </div>
 </div>
```

The head of document calls links as follows:

```
<head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
      <meta name="description" content="#">
      <meta name="keywords" content="#">
      <title>CCIP - CCC | Home</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/normalize.css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/foundation.min.css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="./icomoon/style.css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="./foundation-icons/foundation-icons.css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="./slick/slick.css"/>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css" />
      <script src="./js/vendor/modernizr.js"></script>
  </head>
```

A link to the development site is:
[here](http://staging.nvcc.edu/_ccip_test/index.html)

I know it is probably something simple which I am overlooking but I can find it for the life of me. Any help is appreciated and I can supply more info if needed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of IE are we talking about?

Comment: Add `display:inline-block` on the CSS properties where you are using `:before`.

Comment: @SurrealDreams: all versions. I am currently debugging in IE11.

Comment: @wf4 That was it. Thanks so much. Now I need to research that more to figure out why that was causing an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `:before`  you are not actually inserting anything into the DOM, but instead using CSS to style that extra content into the page. Currently you use `position: absolute;` but you have no width, no height and by default, any pseudo content will flow inline.

To fix your page, add `display:inline-block` on the CSS properties where you are using `:before`. This will tell the pseudo elements to behave like block level elements and they will then work as you are expecting.

e.g.

```
.icon-bookmarks:before, .icon-blog:before, .icon-bullhorn:before, .icon-info2:before, .icon-lab:before, .icon-bookmarks2:before, .icon-bullhorn2:before, .icon-mail:before, .icon-blog2:before, .icon-graduation:before, .icon-user:before, .icon-users2:before {
color: #fff;
font-size: 6rem;
position: absolute;
top: 2.5rem;
display:inline-block; /* <-- add this  */
left: 38%;
left: calc(50% - 5.5rem);
border: 5px solid white;
padding: 2.5rem;
margin-top: 2.5rem;
border-radius: 50%; }
```

Comment: I shouldn't be surprised that is only an issue with IE. Thanks for the thorough explanation.